# C# Posting Keyboard letters using virtual keys not firing

Tags: c#

Basically, I'm trying to send letters (a,b,c) to specific applications in this case a notepad application

Below is the code I'm using and I'm not sure the issue.  When I call the F5 key it seems to work, but none of the other letters in the other methods seem to do anything at all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KeyboardTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { //send keys
            string[] atest = new string[] { "m", "y", "t", "e", "s", "t" };
            KeyboardAction.ExecuteKeys(62016,"hello");
            KeyboardAction.ExecuteKeys(62016, atest);
            KeyboardAction.ExecuteKeys(62016);
        }
        public class KeyboardAction
        {
            const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, string lParam);

            public static void ExecuteKeys(int proc,string[] keys)
            {
                //IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "Notepad - Untitled"); // Window Titel
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(proc);

                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {


                    PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, _key(keys[i]), 0);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, _key(keys[i]), 0);
                }
            }

            public static void ExecuteKeys(int proc,string keys)
            {
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(proc);
                PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, 0, keys);

            }

            public static void ExecuteKeys(int proc)
            {

                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(proc);
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {


                    PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
                    PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0);
                }
            }
            private static int _key(string key)
            {
                string check = key.ToUpper();
                switch (check)
                {
                    case "A":
                        return 0x41;
                    case "B":
                        return 0x42;
                    case "C":
                        return 0x43;
                    case "D":
                        return 0x44;
                    case "E":
                        return 0x45;
                    case "F":
                        return 0x46;
                    case "G":
                        return 0x47;
                    case "H":
                        return 0x48;
                    case "I":
                        return 0x49;
                    case "J":
                        return 0x4A;
                    case "K":
                        return 0x4B;
                    case "L":
                        return 0x4C;
                    case "M":
                        return 0x4D;
                    case "N":
                        return 0x4E;
                    case "O":
                        return 0x4F;
                    case "P":
                        return 0x50;
                    case "Q":
                        return 0x51;
                    case "R":
                        return 0x52;
                    case "S":
                        return 0x53;
                    case "T":
                        return 0x54;
                    case "U":
                        return 0x55;
                    case "V":
                        return 0x56;
                    case "W":
                        return 0x57;
                    case "X":
                        return 0x58;
                    case "Y":
                        return 0x59;
                    case "Z":
                        return 0x5A;
                    default:
                        return 0;

                }



            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the reference I have for virtual key codes: http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html

Comment: @500-InternalServerError why?  SendKeys limitation is it has to be in the active window, which isn't the point.  I also already have a working example just not for all keys.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError and this is exactly why System.InvalidOperationException: 'SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.'

Comment: _I'm trying to send letters (a,b,c) to specific applications in this case a notepad application_: Just because one can send keys to Notepad, doesn't mean the same code will work for other applications. There's really no point in sending keys to Notepad because one can just use [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-8.0) to write the necessary text. What are you trying to achieve? What are the names of the actual applications?